# How do I get reference to an instance of an object from a dynamic created class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dynamic

In my C# app I have an object with for eg. properties `Color` and `Size`, and its populated from db values.

Then I have a designer app that allows a user to add C#/VB code (a whole class with specific methods) that may or may not use/change values from the object's properties

When the app runs the class will be created(codeprovider) in memory from a string created by the designer app, and a specific method called(reflection) at runtime

How do I allow the dynamic code's method to reference my object (non static and populated from user specific data) so that if the user added code for eg:

```
if(TheObject.Color == "Blue")
    TheObject.Width="150";
```

I can get it to work if I pass the object to a method in the dynamic class as an input parameter:

```
....
ocResults = oCodeProvider,CompileAssemblyFromSource(oCParams, userCode);
oAssy = oCResults.CompiledAssembly;
oExecInstance = oAssy.CreateInstance("userClass");
oType = oExecInstance.GetType();
oType.GetMethod("OnLoad", new Type[] { typeof(myObj) });
```

but cant figure out where to put the object so that the dynamic code can reference it (the dynamic code will be generated and executed for each user, but they must reference the object created for their session.

The user's code should be easy to write and not have to get reference from a for eg. static `Dictionary<String,Object>` (referenced via user code `AppDic["UserName"].Color`) and then remove it again from the dictionary when the dynamic code executed.

The user code should just have to be : `TheObject.Color` (like a static method since user code won’t need to create an instance, the code creating the dynamic code already did populated the property values. User must only be able to change/read);

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please format code properly. Also, what language are you asking about?

Comment: `TheObject` damn! i have class with this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, once you found the `MethodInfo` you want on the `Type` you created from the user's code, there is no problem with just sending it the object as a parameter. As in:

```
object userType = ... // compile user's code, load user's type from compiled assembly
MethodInfo myMethod = ... // find the wanted method on the user's type

// assuming the user code is in a static method to avoid having to create instances.
myMethod.Invoke(null, targetObj);
```

If you want the user to only have to writa:

```
theObject.Color;
```

Then you should wrap the user's code to produce something like that:

```
// BEGIN PREFIX
public static class UserType
{
    public static UserMethod(TheObject theObject);
    {
// END PREFIX, user code follows

theObject.Color = Color.Red;

// BEGIN SUFFIX
    }
}
// END SUFFIX
```

By the way, there are some serious security consequences to the design that you chose.

For example, nothing can prevent the user code from doing things that will cause your application to terminate, become unresponsive, or other stuff. Intentionally or not. For example, if the user enters something like `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();`, there's nothing you can do.

The solution to such volnurabilities would be run the user code in a separate `AppDomain`, and send to it the target object, for example through `Remoting`.

**Edit:**  Trying to suggest a way that would not require passing the object as a parameter.

You can create an Assembly with a single class that would expose a static instance of your object. Something like:

```
public class TheInstance
{
    public static TheObject TheObject = new TheObject();
}
```

So now the user code will be able to do things like:

```
TheInstance.TheObject.Color = Color.Red;
```

And you will not have to bother with sending the parameter.

In order for the user code to be able to access the class in this assembly, all you have to do is specify this assembly as a reference when you use the `ICodeCompiler` to compile the user code.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Not too concerned with user code breaking the app. All edits will be logged and since this will be used as a business app, the employee that "broke" the system will be dealt with :) I am using the input parameter method currently

oType.GetMethod("OnLoad", new Type[] { typeof(myObj) }); 

but just thought there must be a way to expose the object from somewhere else to get the same result in the user code you posted:

theObject.Color = Color.Red;

Comment: Kinda, but this is why I originally posted the question.......what will happen if my system is used by say 5000 concurrent users ? Wont they overwrite each other's TheInstance.TheObject causing the user code to fail?